# Prevent Java plugin from attempting to download pack.gz version of the archive

Tags: java, oracle, jvm, webserver, jvm-arguments

The Java 1.7 Plugin insists on attempting to download the pack.gz for the archive file specified.  E.g. for an applet tag like this:

```
<applet codebase="." code="com.whatever.Something" archive="applet/SomethingWhatever.jar" mayscript="true">
<param name="someKindOfSettingA" value="1234">
</applet>
```

We end up with the HTTP server getting requests for:

```
applet/SomethingWhatever.jar.pack.gz
```

I realize we can solve this by providing a pack.gz and this would be beneficial.  But for now I just want to suppress the extra requests.  Is there a way to do this via an applet tag or something?

We tried this:

```
<PARAM NAME="java_arguments" VALUE="-Djnlp.packEnabled=false"/>
```

based on the obvious variation of the instructions here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/tools/pack200.html .  But that made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a JRE bug:

See https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8000291

Regards
Kamil

Answer (score 0):

The most logical setups would be to try both true and fast applet tags:

```
   <APPLET CODE="HelloWorld.class" WIDTH=150 HEIGHT=25>
      <PARAM NAME  = "cache_archive" VALUE = "HelloWorld.jar"/>
      <PARAM NAME="java_arguments" VALUE="-Djnlp.packEnabled=true"/>
   </APPLET>
```

and

```
   <APPLET CODE="HelloWorld.class" WIDTH=150 HEIGHT=25>
      <PARAM NAME  = "cache_archive" VALUE = "HelloWorld.jar"/>
      <PARAM NAME="java_arguments" VALUE="-Djnlp.packEnabled=false"/>
   </APPLET>
```

OR you could try to remove the line, seeing what you get as a result (not garuntees, but it does work occassionally)

```
   <APPLET CODE="HelloWorld.class" WIDTH=150 HEIGHT=25>
      <PARAM NAME  = "cache_archive" VALUE = "HelloWorld.jar"/>
   </APPLET>
```

If none of those work, then you don't really have an option to cancel the call. The call is made to the pack.gz before it goes to the jar, and there isn't a way around this without making a new class that does the same things, but won't make the pack.gz call at all.

Of course, as you said:

> I realize we can solve this by providing a pack.gz and this would be
>   beneficial.

which is what I would just do, as it is a) easier and b) doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: We have tried all three of your applet tag suggestions (and two of them are clearly pointed out in my post) without any difference.

Comment: I didn't think that they would work outside of a very controlled environment (which yours isn't), but it never hurts to check. It seems like the last part of my answer is true "If none of these work... hurt anything" (after 3rd applet tag to the end)

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the latest version of JRE fixes this problem. I had the same problem while running my application with jre 1.7_0_07. But upgrading to jre 1.7_0_11 fixed it.